# Undefined method `within' using capybara and rspec

Tags: rspec, capybara

I'm trying to create a simple rspec that checks for a Bootstrap navigation bar and the appropriate links inside it.  I've included `capybara/rspec` in `spec_helper.rb` and have the rspec in the `spec/features` directory, so I think I have the setup right, but running the spec produces an error stating that the within method is undefined.

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature "HomePage" do 
  before { visit root_path }

  subject { page }

  describe "the navigation bar" do 
    it { should have_selector('.navbar') }

    within ".navbar" do 
      it { should have_link('Game Contest Server', href: root_path) }
      it { should have_link('Users', href: users_path) }
      it { should have_link('Sign Up', href: signup_path) }
    end
  end
end
```

Any ideas for how I can fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In RSpec, the capybara methods are only available inside of an `it` block. You just need to refactor your code into something like:

```
describe "the navigation bar" do 
  it { should have_selector('.navbar') }

  it "should have links" do
     within ".navbar" do 
       should have_link('Game Contest Server', href: root_path)
       should have_link('Users', href: users_path)
       should have_link('Sign Up', href: signup_path)
     end
  end
end
```